# Are relative links valid in <link rel="alternate" hreflang="..." /> tags?

Tags: html

Google's use of `hreflang` is documented [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en%20here) and all the examples have absolute links but there's no mention of absolute links being required or not. I found one post on a [Google group](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/A-sRvQFWn7Q) saying they are required to be absolute but it doesn't seem authoritative and there's no reference. On the other hand [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate) has this example:

```
<link rel=alternate type=application/pdf hreflang=fr href=manual-fr>
```

Can anyone settle this?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the poster did not respond to the OP's request for a reference. A cynic would say that it's because **they couldn't find any**. And they would be right. I don't see any reason `rel=alternate` and the presence of a `hreflang` attribute should require `href` to be an absolute URL. The W3C example makes sense and is something I would expect to see in an everyday document (a link to a translation of the current document - why would it not be easily located relative to the current document?).

Comment: If you're asking whether it's valid HTML, there is no more authoritative reference than W3C HTML5 or the HTML Living Standard (which [has the exact same example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#rel-alternate)). If you're asking whether Google will crawl it correctly, well... Google is not exactly known for being a goody two-shoes when it comes to web standards.

Comment: I guess I will put a relative url, and then I will check whether Google web master tools generates any errors or not. As stated on one of their blog posts, those tools should warn about what Google considers as being erroneous. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077 (I see it in French, have not found an explicit link for an English version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer (from 2015) is wrong.

Here's what the [spec says](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions) today:

> Alternate URLs must be fully-qualified, including the transport method (http/https), so:
> https://example.com/foo, not //example.com/foo or /foo

[image]

---

You can also test your site using https://technicalseo.com/tools/hreflang/, it'll clearly tell you relative urls aren't supported.

---

I believe `alternate` is the keyword here, standard `<link>` can use relative paths, but `rel=alternate` links must use absolute urls.

Comment: Specs says so under section `Guidelines`, which may not be strict requirements.

Answer (score 31):

[Google says clearly in this April 2013 post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html) (under "Mistake 2") that they consider the link tag to accept relative as well as absolute links.

Comment: Nice find. For posterity: the mistake in this case refers to incorrectly-written URLs - Google will ignore "example.com/path/to/cupcake.html" because it is likely to be a mistake meant to have been "/path/to/cupcake.html", but something like "cupcake.html" is fine assuming it is reachable.